# What is a System.FormatException and how can I solve it?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program for a class I have and I keep getting this error:

> System.FormatException (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

```
// Read output to user
Console.WriteLine("               Packing Slip               ");
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine(totalRoomArea + "{0,-30}{1,10:C}", " ft. Wall Area :");
Console.WriteLine(ceilingArea + "{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "ft. Ceiling Area :");
Console.WriteLine(amountOfPaintRequired + "{0,-30}{1,10:C}","gallon(s) " + paintTypeChoice + "      " + "@" + paintPrice + "  =" + paintFinalPrice );
Console.WriteLine(amountOfFlooringRequired + "{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "ft." + flooringTypeChoice + "      " + "@" + flooringPrice + " =" + flooringFinalPrice);
Console.WriteLine(amountOfCasing + "{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "ft. of casing" + "       " + "@" + casingPrice + "=" + casingFinalPrice);
Console.WriteLine(amountOfBaseboardRequired + "{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "ft. of baseboard" + "     " + baseboardPrice + "=" + baseboardFinalPrice);
Console.WriteLine("============================================================================================================");
Console.WriteLine("{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "Net Total" + "      " + "=" + netTotal);
Console.WriteLine("{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "GST" + "      " + "=" + gst);
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("{0,-30}{1,10:C}", "Total" + "        " + "=" + total);
Console.WriteLine("    Press any key to exit... ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You need to show us what is the expected result or tell us what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using string formatters in `Console.WriteLine` i.e {0}, but you are not passing any parameters for that.

You should use them like

```
string.Format("Hello {0}", PersonName);
```

Comment: thanks! worked great!! and thanks to all commenters for their ideas!